# Cannot attach USB to virtual machines

Tags: usb, virtualbox

Im having trouble attaching USB devices to virtual machines. FYI im no IT expert so please bare with me here!! Im running Ubuntu 20.04 as my main OS. I have 3 virtual machines (2 x Ubuntu 10.04 and 1 x Windows 10 pro). All is well with my current setup aside from the USB issue. I have installed Virtualbox 6.1.10 and I have also installed guest additions and extension packs.

I insert the USB and I can see it attaches and works fine in the main OS. But when I go to a VM and select devices>USB I get error message "Failed to create a proxy device for the USB device.(Error VERR_PDM_NO_USB_PORTS).

I read online that version 6.1.10 of virtualbox had bugs regarding this so I also have 6.1.2 installed. Could this be my conflict? Also within the Virtualbox VM settings i have toggled between USB2/3 option but this makes no difference.

I will be honest im dubious about uninstalling things on Ubuntu as im not familiar with the terminal commands.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to look at my issue.

Comment: I have just re installed virtualbox 6.1.10 guest additions and selected USB3 for all of my virtual machines in the virtualbox settings. Now windows 10 is good and i can use the USB. With my other two virtual machines i no longer get the "Failed to create.....NO USB PORTS" error it looks like it has attached but i cant find it anywhere in the VM!! I go to computer and theres no option for USB stick!!

Comment: A workaround is to establish a shared folder that resides on the host, accessed from the guest. Place a symlink to the usb drive in that shared folder and then the guest can access the usb drive...

Answer (score 0):

10.04LTS can only recognise USB sticks 8GB or less. Issue resolved.